# Android Application - displaying a static map with near by options

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to display a Google Map in my Android Application. Map will be of static kind with near by transport options.

I am bit confused about which API to use. Can someone provide me some guidance about it - perhaps some example/tutorial links would be mighty helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the maps truly are static, you can create the static images using the [Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) and download the images and include them into your Android project and use an ImageView to display them. If you could provide more information, I think we could definitively point you in the correct direction.

Are the maps static with respect to a users position? If so, they aren't static.
Are you trying to provide walking directions?
Are you trying to provide ANY directions?